# Return javascript output for option select

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on these codes for awhile and need some help. Basically, I'm trying to get the result or output of the script and put it in between the option select as shown here:

```
<select class="form-control" name="property_list">
  *insert output javascript here               
</select>
```

Below is the complete script. Would this method be possible?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#client-list").on('change', function postinput(){
        var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'sql/client-to-property.php',
            data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function(responseData) {
            console.log('Done: ', responseData);
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('Failed');
        });
    });
  }); 
</script>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-addon gi data-gi-size gi-user-add"></span>
  <select id="client-list" name="client-list">
     <?php
       $sql = "SELECT `id`, `email`
               FROM `clients` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
       $result = $DB_CON_C->query($sql);

       if($result !== false) {
         $data_row = '<option>New Client</option>' . "\n";
         foreach($result as $row) {
           $data_row .=  '<option>' .$row['email'] . '</option>' . "\n";
         }
      }
      unset($row);
      echo $data_row;
    ?>
  </select>
</div>

<select class="form-control" name="property_list">
  *insert output javascript here               
</select>
```

Comment: you want to display the data from database in the `select`?

Comment: yes, the ajax script that I have returns a couple of options for my option select. I just need those options between the option select so the user can choose. Forgot to mention that the result of the script was generated from client-to-property.php.

Comment: the returned data is in html format?

Comment: I believe the returned data in html will work for the option select since the texts generated from the php contain the options for select.

Comment: Could you share the response of the ajax request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to add returned data to the `select`, in your done function get select by `name` and add the data. This will work if the returned data is in the following format:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#client-list").on('change', function postinput(){
        var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sql/client-to-property.php',
            data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function(responseData) {
            console.log(responseData);
            var data = JSON.parse(responseData);
            $('select[name="property_list"]').html(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log('Failed');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, julekgwa. There are no errors but the select is blank. There are no options returned.

Comment: @ubuntujavy `console.log`  responseData, and see if data is returned fro `PHP`

Comment: The return from the client-to-property.php is in this format: [<option value="New Property">New</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option>]. But the code your supplied is not working.

Comment: are you echoing as a string or using `json_encode`?

Comment: where or how do I look for console.log for the response data? sorry I'm new at this stuff and trying to learn.

Comment: I don't think I'm echoing as a string. Here is the script from client-to-property.php:  <?php
  require 'db.php';
  
    $book_name = $_POST['matchvalue'];
    $sql = "SELECT `id`
              FROM `".$book_name."` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $result = $DB_CON_C->query($sql);

    if($result !== false) {
      $data_row = '<option value="New Property">New</option>';

      foreach($result as $row) {
        $data_row .=  '<option>' .$row['id'] . '</option>';
      }
    }
    unset($row);
    echo $data_row;

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your response data and append options to your property list like so:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#client-list").on('change', function postinput(){
        var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value
        $.ajax({ 
          url: 'sql/client-to-property.php',
          data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
          type: 'post'
        }).done(function(responseData) {
          console.log('Done: ', responseData);

          var data = JSON.parse(responseData); // Assuming response data is a JSON string
          data.each(function(i, property) {
            $("input[name=property_list]").append("<option />").text(property);
          });
        }).fail(function() {
          console.log('Failed');
        });
      });
    });
```

The options will need values as well so you can add that attribute to the options too:

```
$("input[name=property_list]").append("<option />").attr('value', property).text(property);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I receive error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.